# Scale image on seperate div hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

See: https://jsfiddle.net/8osg70fp/

I have an image on the right-hand side of the page that I want to scale like in the fiddle, when a div on the opposite side is hovered on.

I know its something along this format, but I cant get it to work.

```
var treecontainer=document.getElementById('treecontainer'); //DIV=TREECONTAINER
$(treecontainer).mouseover(function(){
    /*CHANGE IMAGE'S CSS HERE*/    
});
$(treecontainer).mouseleave(function(){
    /*CHANGE IMAGE'S CSS BACK HERE*/    
});
```

Comment: So can you paste your html along with your script code and  let us know what is not working.Better if you will create a fiddle example for your problem

Comment: can you post the complete relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look. Let me know if this is not what you need.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 20px;
}

.myhover {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.myhover:hover + .scaleme {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="myhover"></div>
  <img class="scaleme" src="http://placehold.it/100">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you're looking for

js

```
  $('div').mouseenter(function(){
     $('.secondone').css({transform:'scale(1.5)'});
 });
$('div').mouseleave(function(){
     $('.secondone').css({transform:'scale(1)'});
 });
```

css

```
div {
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background-color:black;
  margin:5% 30%;
  transition:.5s ease;
}

<div></div>
<div class="secondone"></div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JJREbL

Answer (score 0):

You don´t need any javascript to do this. If you use a CSS scale transformation on hover state, you´ll have exactly the same effect without unnecessary JavaScript.

Only with few lines of CSS

```
div {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/random);
    transition:.5s ease;
}

div.first:hover + div.second {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

Check my pen - https://codepen.io/Legues/pen/LLRxQg

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

CSS

```
div {
margin: 150px;
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
background-color: yellow;
border: 1px solid black;
transition: all 3s;
}

.div1:hover+ .div2 {
 border: 1px solid black;
-ms-transform: scale(2,3); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: scale(2,3); /* Safari */
transform: scale(2,3); /* Standard syntax */
transition: all 3s;
}
```

URL: [Check demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8osg70fp/6/)